# H20 and Cloudera Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321

Tags: cloudera, h2o

Starting H2O from a Cloudera Gateway node and it comes back with the following:

```
Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321
```

less command on /etc/hosts shows the following (I needing it to use 10.x.2xx.2x or the DNS name)

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.x.2xx.2x   xxx-xshcxxwd12 xxx-xshcxxwd12.xxx.net
```

Suggestion/insights/ideas?

```
  Update #1
```

Since our ifconfig and the output from the startup of H2O shows the following:

```
    <b>Startup of H2O:</b>
    Determining driver host interface for mapper->driver callback.
    [Possible callback IP address: 10.2.219.27]
    [Possible callback IP address: 10.18.73.77]
    [Possible callback IP address: 127.0.0.1]</code>

<b>ifconfig shows:</b>
    1. eth0 : addr:10.2.219.27
    2. eth1: addr:10.18.73.77 
    3. lo :  addr:127.0.0.1
```

We utilized the -baseport and set it to 9100, which did change the port number. 
`Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:9100`

From the same host we performed wget on all three Ip Addresses with results of:

```
    [@usadc-shdcxp01 ]$ wget 127.0.0.1:9100
    --2017-05-01 16:12:19--  http://127.0.0.1:9100/
    Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9100... failed: Connection refused.
```

Even with the default port of :54321 we got the same results.

Tom K: spoke of using  `-network` yet I am setting up a single gateway.. Setting a network range resulted in the following:
    'ERROR: network invalid: 10.18.73.0/77`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Now is it off topic?

Comment: What exactly is your question??

Comment: The question could be rephrased as:  "How can I get H2O Flow to bind to a real interface instead of localhost?"

Comment: The error message is correct. /77 is invalid.  Try /24.  The /X specifies the number of leftmost bits that are used to specify the interface to match.  So you can't have more than 32.

Answer (score 0):

H2O tries to figure out a suitable network interface to bind to, but some network setups are tricky and it sometimes needs you to specify what you want on the command line.

If you are running H2O standalone (java -jar h2o.jar ...), you can specify the `-ip a.b.c.d` command-line option to tell H2O exactly which interface to bind to.

If you are running H2O on Hadoop (hadoop jar h2odriver.jar ...), you can specify the `-network a.b.c.d/e` command-line option to specify a range of interface addresses to bind to.  This is because the individual hosts the mapper containers get placed on varies (they are chosen by the YARN resource manager), so you need to provide an appropriate mask that will match for all the possible nodes.

For example, if ifconfig says that your gateway node has ip address 10.2.3.4, then

```
hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -network 10.2.3.0/24 ...
```

or

```
hadoop jar h2odriver.jar -network 10.2.0.0/16 ...
```

might be good choices.